# Validate uniqueness of child objects in Rails nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parent-child, nested-forms, validates-uniqueness-of

I have a form for Library, which has several nested objects for Librarian. My question is:

How can I validate uniqueness of Librarian's name? (there may be multiple librarians for one library, but there should not be the same librarian appears twice). I found a hint but couldn't make it work:

```
    validates_uniqueness_of :task_name, :scope => :project_id
```

Please give me an example, because I found pieces to the puzzle but have not been able to put them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Librarian` has `library_id`:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :library_id
```

Comment: Hi nash, are you saying that by default, Library has access to :name attribute of Librarian? I did this in libraries_controller but I got error saying name is undefined.

Comment: Stop, why do you do it in libraries_controller? You should put it in the Librarian model. It would be helpful if you show us your models.

Comment: Hi nash, sorry, I am doing it in model but got the error saying name is undefined.